# Google Analytics API comparitive period pervious year

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The Google Anlaytics Web Interface has a checkbox where you can compare your data to the previous year. I am running queries in java with the API and was wondering if anyone has noticed the same functionality built into the API?

right now I am running queries like this:

```
GaData gaData = analytics.data().ga().get(tableID, startDate, endDate, metrics).setDimensions(dimensions).execute();
```

is there a way to include the previous year automatically or do i have to query that by hand?

Comment: You'll have to build another query to get YOY data. The checkbox in the UI is simply a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the API doesn't allow any period-over-period comparison. You will have to do this manually.

Smart way to do this is to get data on daily basis and then simply group them (pivot tables) on any level required: weeks/moths/quarters/years.

Comment: I just ended up running a second query with Date = Date - 1 Year thanks

Comment: Awesome, glad I could "help". I hope Google will update the APIs so that these tasks become easier, even though as I have  said, I prefer to extract data on daily basis and then do all the math by myself in Excel. Helps to avoid sampling too.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the ga:Year dimension to your query you will get the results based upon each year.  Then you can run your own compaire on each year thats returned.